# Resolution of a problem concerning calligraphic fonts such as \mathcal or \pazocal

Tags: math-mode, equations, bold, mathtools, amssymb

Although the question may seem very simple, I want to ask it because I wish to learn. I use a lot of packages for my book and unfortunately someone goes into conflict. For example, I can't use `bm` package. I was wondering because even if I put or not put a blank space after 2 to the symbol/command `\boldsymbol{\mathcal{U}}`, it doesn't separate (see picture). For the symbol `\cdot` next to the symbol `\boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}` the blank space exists because I think the first one is an operator and the other one is a character. The empty space is created by default. My question is: to create space in these cases I must necessarily use space `\,`?

Here there are my MWE and the image:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsbsy}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
\[
2 \boldsymbol{\mathcal{U}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\mathcal{A}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shape conflicts should be solved on a case by case analysis: in this case `2\,\boldsymbol{U}` seems necessary; probably not for `2\boldsymbol{A}`.

Comment: `\,` might be a bit too much, try `\mkern1mu\boldsymbol{\mathcal{U}}`  (`\, ` is 3mu normally)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and egreg: Mine is just a mere curiosity and I thank you very much for your comments.Please could you give me an answer instead of a comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: @egreg I also appreciate any response you may have. Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this manually, although of course you can define macros for the common ones in any document.  `\,` might be a bit too much (although it is personal judgement) perhaps

```
2 \mkern1mu\boldsymbol{\mathcal{U}}
```

(`\,` is 3mu normally)